# Using the same javascript function twice in one page

Tags: javascript

I'm using a javascript function on [this site](http://fawky.de/fawky/powerbikes/werkstatt.html#elektrik) to have a slideshow of images.
However, when I try to copy the javascript function and use it for example for "Bremsen". It doesn't work. Is there anyway, that you can give a javascript an ID, so that both animations work at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are using the same variables. Right now the solution would be renaming the variables youre using in every instance of the function like:

```
var stepX=1
function slideitX(){

document.images.slidee.src=eval("imagee"+stepX+".src")
if (stepX>5)
stepX++
else
stepX=1

setTimeout("slideitX()",3000)
}
slideitX()
```

But tha's not a good practice, I agree with @killercowuk

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working now. I Know it's bad practice, but as I said above my timeframe is very limited. Once I know enough Javascript I'll change all that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry people have down-voted your question so badly, without providing a valid reason! (This is poor etiquette) but the javascript at your given link is not well written and its lack of [modularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_design) actually prevents you from using it more than once on a single page.

Each Javascript function must have a unique name (in a given [namespace](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/bestpractices/#namespace)), however in your example you are trying to define two functions that are both called "slideit".

I don't think I could describe to you how to get this job done effectively from here. You need to learn how to code javascript properly (learn to use and store information in Objects and pass variables to functions);

Start by learning the [basics](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp) and then learn to use a framework such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) which provides access to many useful functions for getting the job done quickly and (relatively) easily.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just took that code from google, because as you saw I know almost nothing about Javascript. The site needs to be finished in about 2 weeks, so I don't really have enough time to learn Javascript. As a last resort I can still make the animation with Photoshop. What you are saying is, I have to rename slideit each time, for it to work? Edit: Thanks to jcespionza and you it's working.

Comment: No problem, glad you managed to work with what you've got - and hope you get to grips with Javascript one day, its a cool language to work with to make kick-ass web sites :)